# How to write to log file when test fail, with Log4j

Tags: java, testing, exception, log4j

I want to achieve writing to ***log*** file with `Log4j`.

I have found one easy solution - surround test body with `try - catch`:

```
@Test(groups = "GMAIL_PAGE")
public void testAllMailLink() {
    try {
        List<WebElement> allMessages = page.takeAllMessage();
        page.clickInboxLink();
        List<WebElement> inboxMessages = page.takeInboxMessage();
        page.clickDraftLink();
        List<WebElement> draftMessages = page.takeDraftMessage();

        Assert.assertTrue(allMessages.containsAll(inboxMessages),
                "All messages doesn't contains all inbox messages");
        Assert.assertTrue(allMessages.containsAll(draftMessages),
                "All messages doesn't contains all draft messages");
        log.info("test is passed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

But it has some drawbacks - this test is always passed, even if it fails.

It is ok if I work on my machine and able to see console. But what to do when this test is pushed to Continuous Integration server?

***Does exist any other way to write info into log file, when test fail?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Assert.fail()` below your `log.error(e)`:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e);
    Assert.fail();
}
```

By the way, you're calling [`Logger#error(Object)`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object%29), which uses `e.toString()`. In this case, it is better to use a descriptive message and then pass the exception to get the respective stacktrace:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Some descriptive message should go here.", e);
    Assert.fail("Some descriptive message should go here as well.");
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest some other methods for loging failed test?

Comment: @nazar_art how are you running your tests?

Comment: At Intellij - `Cntrl` + `Shift` + `F10` with testNG.

Comment: or I misunderstood your question.